# How do I replace an underscore with a dash using htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay here is my url:

`http://example.com/home/process_login`

I would like to replace the underscore with a dash.

So `http://example.com/home/process-login` will go to the above url, but it will still SAY `process-login` in the URL bar.

Hopefully this makes sense. The only solutions I've found have been redirects, and I don't want a redirect. I want it to read as I have outlined.

Comment: Please use the search: [\[mod-rewrite\] underscore hypen](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmod-rewrite%5D+underscore+hyphen&submit=search) or [\[mod-rewrite\] underscore dash](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmod-rewrite%5D+underscore+dash&submit=search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(home/)(.*)-(.*)$ $1$2_$3 [L,NC]
```

**UPDATE: Based on your comments below**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(coremeasures/index\.php/|index\.php|home/|images/|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /coremeasures/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(home/)(.*)-(.*)$ $1$2_$3 [L,NC]
```

**UPDATE 2: Based on your comments below**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?!(coremeasures/index\.php/|index\.php|home/|images/|robots\.txt))(.*)$ coremeasures/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(home/)(.*)-(.*)$ $1$2_$3 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Here's my .htaccess, I'm getting a 404 for `http://example.com/home/process-login`

`Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /coremeasures/index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(home/)(.*)-(.*)$ $1$2_$3 [L,NC]`

Comment: Your code has some issues, I have fixed it and updated my answer. Pls check code in **UPDATE** section above.

Comment: Pls provide matching logs from access.log and error.log files here for further investigation.

Comment: It has an issue with this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(index\.php|home/|images/|robots\.txt)`

Comment: Well that line works fine in my testing but as I requested earlier also if you can show matching logs from access.log and error.log files here, it will be easy for me to fix/suggest the alternative. Meanwhile you can try code from **Update 2** above.